# Can Nodemailer transports send email synchronously?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have a nodejs fs loop which iterates through a directory, encodes the file as base64 and sends using Nodemailer.

The issue is that Nodemailer will call the callback once the email has been sent, effectively exhausting all the javascript process memory (since each file is around 2M and there are 700 of them).

Is there a way of making Nodemailer send mail and block the loop until the message has been sent, then continue?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've arrived at is a complete hack.

Basically wrapping the whole read -> encode -> send block in a setTimeout which increments by x seconds each loop iteration. This effectively slows down the execution of the processing.